# Nested Stack Navigator and Drawer Navigator in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a couple of issues with setup Stack Navigator and Drawer Navigator. First and foremost, the below picture is the flow that I expected and I followed the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/common-mistakes) provided by the React Navigation to implement but I have no luck to achieve what I expected and the output of the implementation looks so weird (You can find it on the 2nd picture). I also attached my code snippet at the bottom.

Also, the output looks like the Drawer navigator header is duplicated with the Stack Navigator.

Besides that, I am quite new to React Native. I hope someone makes me more clearer how the implementation should look like because I have come across few articles and websites, their solution does not work in my case.

P/S: Screen X is opened when one of item clicked from Screen C

[image]

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Image,
    Button,
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    ScrollView,
    View,
    Text,
    StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator, DrawerActions, DrawerItems } from 'react-navigation-drawer';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import HomeScreen from '../HomeScreen';
import ItemDetailScreen from '../ItemDetailScreen'; 
import ProfileScreen from '../ProfileScreen';
const navOptionsHandler = (navigation) => {
    header: null
}
const CustomDrawerComponent = (props) => (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Image source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/logo.png' }} style={{
                height: 120,
                width: 120,
                borderRadius: 60
            }} />
        </View>
        <ScrollView>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
        </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
)


const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
    {
        Home: {
            screen: HomeScreen
        },
        Profile: {
            screen: ProfileScreen
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Home",
        contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
        contentOptions: {
            activeTintColor: 'orange'
        }
    }
);
const MyStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        HomeA: {
            screen: MyDrawerNavigator
        },
        ItemDetail: {
            screen: ItemDetailScreen,
            navigationOptions: navOptionsHandler
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "HomeA"
    }
);


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyStackNavigator);

export default class StackNavigator extends Component {
    render() {
        return <AppContainer />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawer navigator is encapsulated by the stack navigator, which is why you have a double header.
What you need to do is to have the drawer navigator as your main navigator, and have your stack navigator as your profile screen, so it will be displayed as you click on "Profile" in your drawer navigator.

This should work:

```js
const navOptionsHandler = navigation => {
  null
}
const CustomDrawerComponent = props => (
  <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
      style={{ height: 150, backgroundColor: 'white', alignItems: 'center' }}
    >
      <Image
        source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/logo.png' }}
        style={{
          height: 120,
          width: 120,
          borderRadius: 60,
        }}
      />
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
      <DrawerItems {...props} />
    </ScrollView>
  </SafeAreaView>
)

const MyStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: ProfileScreen,
    ItemDetail: {
      screen: ItemDetailScreen,
      navigationOptions: navOptionsHandler,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Profile',
  },
)

const MyDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Home: HomeScreen,
    ProfileStack: {
      screen: MyStackNavigator,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        title: 'Profile',
      }),
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerComponent,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'orange',
    },
  },
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MyDrawerNavigator)

export default class StackNavigator extends Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />
  }
}
```

By the way since you say you are only just starting using React Native, unless you have a specific reason to use React Navigation v4, you should probably use v5 instead as v4 will become obsolete one day or another.

Comment: I have implemented the solution that provided by you but there's a problem when the ItemDetailScreen is navigated by the Home Screen and pressed back button from the ItemDetailScreen, it will navigate back me to ProfileScreen. (The expect output as it should pop back the parent who navigate it, in this case, the ItemDetailScreen should navigate back to HomeScreen). 

* P/S: I have implemented this.props.navigation.navigate.goBack() and this.props.navigation.navigate.pop() but it does not function as I expected.

Comment: @MiracleHades that's the normal behaviour. When you press the back button, you are going back in the stack you are in, which is the profile stack in your example. If you really want to do that (and I don't think you should, as it would be very confusing for the user), I _think_ using `push` (or maybe `reset` or `replace`) instead of `navigate` would help. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-actions/

Comment: The reason I plan to implement this solution because that ItemDetailScreen is reused by ProfileScreen and HomeScreen in most cases. If I can achieve reuse, it increases the maintainability of the app itself.

Comment: I have applied StackActions.dispatch() and this.props.navigation.popToTop(), both of the solution are not perform any different with the goBack() operation.

Comment: What do you mean by reused? If you want to have the same screen in different navigation stacks, you can do that.

Comment: Reused means the ItemDetailScreen is shared by ProfileScreen and HomeScreen.
For e.g., when ItemDetailScreen is navigated by ProfileScreen, the back action should back to ProfileScreen.
In another case, when ItemDetailScreen is navigated by HomeScreen, the back action should back to HomeScreen.

Comment: Then you need to have two navigation stacks: `MyStackNavigator` that you already have, and a new one with `HomeScreen` and `ItemDetailScreen` that you will put in the drawer navigator.